# OpenCL error: CL_INVALID_PROGRAM OpenCL error: CL_INVALID_PROGRAM

Tags: eclipse, opencl, ubuntu-16.04

ubuntu16.04+eclipse+opencl+cuda;
I can run my project in Terminal, and everything is ok, but i need change code and debug my code, so i build a project in eclipse with no error, but when i debug or run my code, the console show these error:

```
Unable to open ../assets/cvc.cl. ../../src/oclUtil.cpp:445
Failed to create OpenCL program.../../src/CVC_cl.cpp:25
OpenCL error: CL_INVALID_PROGRAM
Failed to create OpenCL kernel. ../../src/CVC_cl.cpp:77
```

my code is ok, and i can run in terminal. I don't know why, please help me. thanks!

Comment: "my code is ok" - well, something is clearly not OK, so you'll need to provide more information, such as the code for which you're getting the error, and maybe the host code you're using to compile the OpenCL code.

Comment: Probably a path was specified incorrectly somewhere so that relative paths are resolved incorrectly (`../../src` looks odd if `src` is a subfolder of the project folder).

Answer (score 0):

Use more error checking at your build f.e.

```
 // Build the program                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &deviceId, NULL, NULL, NULL); RC_TEST2(ret, "clBuildProgram");                                                                                                                                                                                         

  if(ret != CL_SUCCESS){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    size_t len = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

    clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, deviceId, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 0, NULL, &len);                                                                                                                                                                                                        

    char *buffer = calloc(len, sizeof(char));                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    ret = clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, deviceId, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, len, buffer, NULL);                                                                                                                                                                                              
    fprintf(stderr, "%s", buffer);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    exit(1);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  }
```

But in your case its clear that path to cl file is wrong. So compiler unable to build kernel. Something wrong with relative path. Try to use absolute path if u unable to fix that.